# Fusionar dos repositorios git distintos sin perder commits

Tags: git, git-commit

Partiendo de dos repositorios **DISTINTOS** de Git.

El primero **A** como repositorio remoto BitBucket. (Con 280 commits de código).
El segundo **B** como repositorio remoto GitLab. (Con 20 commits de documentación).

Necesito combinar ambos repositorios, sin perder ningun commit para subirlo todo al de GitLab, es decir, en otras palabras, necesito actualizar el repositorio **B** con todos los commits del repositorio **A** sin perder ningun commit en ambos. (No existe la posibilidad de que hayan conflictos, ya que el contenido de ambos repositorios es totalmente distinto)

Como resultado, deseo que el repositorio **B** contenga en GitLab **TODOS** los commits de ambos repositorios, es decir, que contenga 300 commits en total, sin haber perdido nada en el proceso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución al problema es realizar lo siguiente:

Desde el repositorio **B** de GitLab, con 20 líneas de código, añadir un repositorio remoto nuevo que apunte al repositorio **A**, del que se quieren obtener los commits:

`git remote add repoA https://Bitbucket.....`

Estando en el repositorio **B**, una vez añadido el repositorio remoto **A** hacer un pull de **A** con la opción **--allow-unrelated-histories** y la rama a la que queremos traer los commits.

`git pull repoA --allow-unrelated-histories master`

(Puede que despues de hacer esto, tendremos que realizar `git add *` y `git commit` para crear un nuevo commit equivalente a un merge de ambos repositorios **A** y **B**, a veces no es necesario, ya que a veces se crea automáticamente el commit con el mensaje de merge)

En este punto tendremos en el repositorio **B** los 20 commits que ya teníamos y los 280 del repositorio **A**, una vez hecho esto, ya podríamos subir a GitLab todos los cambios realizados en el rempo **B**.

`git push repoA master`

Ya tendríamos en el repositorio **B** en GitLab los 300 commits de ambos repositorios y un commit más que es el resultado de la mezcla.

La unica desventaja de este proceso, es que la fecha de todos los commits añadidos en el repositorio de GitLab tendrán **TODOS** la fecha actual.